# How to add a texture color specificed "glow" to a HUD panel?

Tags: node-editor, shaders

I've been trying to figure this out,
I'm using Blender 2.79 and the new Principled shader but it doesn't have an  alpha channel or an emissive channel built in (yet?). I can accomplish what I'm trying to do below in C4D but I'm trying to switch entirely to Blender. I have a material that's called "glow" that gets applied to HUD and LED
type panels in a spaceship which has an alpha channel.

Here's a wide image of my node setup
[image: How do I add a glow type color emissive to a material]

I'd like to have the emissive match the color of the diffuse map (minus any black) and have the alpha applied so only the color in the diffuse is emitting light for this material.

If I have to create a modified tiff from the diffusion with alpha texture to make one specifically for emissive that's okay.. just want to know how best to accomplish this?
Thank you very much!
I'm new to blender and it's absolutely amazing!

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out
[image: How to create glow in blender nodes with alpha]

Just had to plug the texture directly into emissive color instead of trying to use the output from the principle BSDF into emissive color. This works! Problem solved.